# Prove continuity of function from normed space to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> We have $(X,||.||)$ as normed space. Prove that $f: X$->$\mathbb{R}$, $x$->$||x||^2$ is continouos.

My attempt:
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
We have the induced metric $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$.
Let $x \in X$ with $d(x,x_0) = ||x-x_0|| < \delta$ then
$d(f(x), f(x_0)) = ||f(x)-f(x_0)|| = || ||x||^2-||x_0||^2|||$
This is the point where I stuck. Can someone tell a hint?

Comment: If $x$ is a vector $x^2$ isn't necessarily well defined, do you perhaps mean $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By the inverse triangle inequality, the function $f(x)=||x||$ is continuous. Also, the function $g(t)=t^2$ is continuous.

Comment: How can you use inverse triangle inequality with that many $||$?

Comment: The inverse triangle inequality states that $| \; ||x||-||y|| \; | \leq ||x-y||$. Can you see how it proves the continuity of the norm?

Comment: Yes but we have $||||x|| - ||y||||$

Comment: ||x||-||y|| is an expression in the real numbers.

Comment: Can you make an exact example what it would look like in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Its just the value of your norm, which is a a real number. For example, if you take the euclidean norm and $x=(1,1)$ it becomes $||x||=\sqrt{x \cdot x}=\sqrt{2}$ where $\cdot$ denotes the standard scalar product.

Comment: Ok, so can we also write $||$ $||x|| - ||y||$ $||$ $\leq$ $||x-y||$?

Comment: You can, but the out $||$ are just a norm on $\mathbb{R}$. Which can just be the absolut value. A good way to make it clearer would be:  
$|| \; ||x||_X-||y||_X \; ||_{\mathbb{R}} \leq ||x-y||_X $